# Access Controls on Files, Folders, and Other System Objects in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, uac

Why do other users have to Run as Administrator and I don't?

I have an executable file, which I placed in a folder on the C drive of a server.

We all remote desktop in to access this server. We are all in the local admin group.

When I remote in I can double-click the executable file and it runs with no problem.

When other users double click it the cursor changes to an hourglass for a split second and then the executable file processes exit (as seen in process explorer).

When other users right click and select Run as Administrator the executable file runs with no problems.

The application files were just copied straight into the folder on the C drive. I tried moving the folder somewhere else and the behavior is the same.

So, why do other users have to Run as Administrator and I don't and how can troubleshoot/fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First, an assumption. If the app does not have write access to this folder, it will close.

This means that you have write access to that folder, and the other users don't. Probably because you created the folder, and as owner you have Full Access.

The other users have read-only access because the permissions for Users on that folder are set to read-only, but Administrators has Full Access. So when they double-click, it's launched with Users permissions (read). When they Run as Administrator, it's launched with the Administrators permissions (Full Access).

To fix this problem, either assign Users Full Access to that folder, or create another group for these users and assign that group Full Access.

Comment: It shows the owner as the local admin group which we are all a part of and there are no user specific permissions under security.

Comment: Are you an explicit member of the local Administrators group? Are the other people? Is your account local, or domain? What about the other people.

Comment: Everyone's situation is the same except that I copied the application files to the folder. Someone told me (since posting this question) they have seen similar issues on this server with another app so I am starting to think it is something with this server and not windows in general. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is almost certainly a permissions issue. You're on the right track using procmon. What you need to do now is run procmon while opening the app with your account, and again with someone else. Then filter for `ACCESS DENIED` and see what is being denied for the other users that isn't for you. That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly a permissions problem; if not on the folder containing the executable, then on one of the files, or somewhere else on the file system.

The most effective way to troubleshoot this sort of problem is usually Process Monitor, available for download from the Microsoft web site.

If the problem does not occur on other servers, the root cause might be something specific to the server, e.g., perhaps the permissions have been changed on the root of the C drive or on the Program Data folder.  Process Monitor is still the best bet for identifying the problem.